# WebSphere Returning 503 Error(Servlet has become temporarily unavailable for service) on Static File

Tags: websphere, static-files, http-status-code-503

I have a WebSphere 8.5.0 application server for development.  It is returning a 503 error on a static JavaScript file.

This is the HTML that is returned with the error:

```
<H1>Servlet has become temporarily unavailable for service</H1><BR><H3></H3><BR><I>IBM WebSphere Application Server</I>
```

- I tried replacing the file with a blank text file. The server still returned the same 503 error.
- I tried changing the name of the file, and it returned the file correctly with the new name and the server returned 404 if I tried the original name.

I figured there would be a solution somewhere online for this, but I couldn't find it.

I found two possible leads:

- The file is somehow locked on the server.
- There is a routing issue.

If it matters, I deploy the application to the server as an ear file.

I checked all the logs and the only thing that appears in any of them is this in SystemOut:

```
[2/10/15 8:50:31:696 PST] 00001b48 webcontainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer sendUnavailableException Servlet.has.become.temporarily.unavailable.for.service 
[2/10/15 8:50:33:120 PST] 00001b48 webcontainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer sendUnavailableException Servlet.has.become.temporarily.unavailable.for.service
```

And I should probably mention that the exact same ear file is deployed on my local machine and 2 production servers with no problems.  It is just my development server that has the problem.

Comment: Logs/ffdcs?  Can't diagnose this from browser output.

Comment: Went through logs, edited question.

Answer (score 2):

After deploying an new version of an application, the
this message appear in the Websphere output

This then requires a restart of the server in order for app
processing to continue. The problem is due to the way that
cached servlet wrappers are handled when an application
is destroyed upon redeploy.

Restarting the server after redeploy is the current local fix.

you can visit :

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK47748

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with was 8.0.0, I tried using a blank file, also changing the file name, but nothing works. The log didn't tell me anything about the problem. Always the same message:

```
<H1>Servlet has become temporarily unavailable for service</H1><BR><H3></H3><BR><I>IBM WebSphere Application Server</I>
```

The solution was restart the server, maybe the problem was that the file was locked by some kind of process.